# Send a post request using NodeJS

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to send a post request to a service installed on a pi. here is the app I'm using :

```
const http = require('http')

const data = JSON.stringify({
    Name:"MYONE",

})

const options = {
  hostname: 'http://127.0.0.1',
  port: 11555,
  PATH:'/api/config',
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Content-Length': data.length
  }


}

const req = http.request(options, (res) => {
  console.log(`statusCode: ${res.statusCode}`)

  res.on('data', (d) => {
    process.stdout.write(d)
  })
})

req.on('error', (error) => {
  console.error(error)
})

req.write(data)
req.end()
```

The app should change the name of the device.,and based on the documentation the return status should be 200 in case "everything went good" 
running the app I get the following:

```
node app.js 




statusCode: 200
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Frameset//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/frameset.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>Changing device name </title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/style.css" />
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
</head>
<frameset rows="52,20,16,*" frameborder="0" framespacing="0" border="0">
  <frameset cols="*,771,*" frameborder="0" framespacing="0" border="0">
    <frame src="/menu?logo=b" noresize scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" framespacing="0" frameborder="0" border="0">
    <frame name="toplogo" src="/menu?logo=t" noresize scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" framespacing="0" frameborder="0" border="0">
    <frame src="/white.html" noresize scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" framespacing="0" frameborder="0" border="0">
  </frameset>
  <frame name="navibar" src="/menu" noresize scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" framespacing="0" frameborder="0" border="0">
  <frame name="submenu" src="/grey.html" noresize scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" framespacing="0" frameborder="0" border="0">
  <frame name="content" src="/menu?info=Browser" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" framespacing="0" frameborder="0" border="0">
<noframes>You must use a browser with frame support to see this page.</noframes>
</frameset>
</html>
```

In the end I get status code 200 but the device name doesn't change. 
Any idea what I'm missing here? 
I wish I could deliver more info on the service, but I don't have any.

Comment: The request looks ok. Could you please post the `/api/config` endpoint? It looks like after receiving the POST request it responds with an HTML page and the name change should be made on that page. Are you sure you are not missing something out?

Comment: @SebastianKaczmarek thanks for replying. I'm sure that I'm missing smt. I've been looking for the /api/config but couldn't find it :(

Comment: Maybe you need to reboot the device to apply these changes?